# How to setup DNS forwarding for a VPS's subdomain without domain name? CENTOS 6 & Bind9

Tags: apache, dns, bind

a CENTOS 6 VPS (say IP 1.2.3.4), LAMP,Bind 9, no domain hosted;
some web applications are installed in the form of sub-domain http://1.2.3.4/app 
i'd like to setup one subdomain as a kind of DDNS, when http://1.2.3.4/abc is accessed, it need be resolved pointing as an external IP address.

Tried adding /etc/named.conf options

```
options {
forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any;};
allow-query     { localhost; any;};

....
zone "abc" IN {
    type master;
    file "abc.zone";
};
```

abc.zone file added under /var/named

```
$TTL 600
@       IN      SOA     abc. root.abc. (
                                    0      ; serial
                                    3H      ; refresh
                                    1H      ; retry
                                    2D      ; expire
                                    3H )    ; minimum
;
@       IN      NS      abc.
@      IN      A      1.2.3.4 (for example)
abc    IN      A      2.3.4.5 (external IP sample)
```

When i ping http://1.2.3.4/abc, it just says no such host.

Any hint or information are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You have things mixed up. `/abs` is not a subdomain. DNS has nothing to do with `http://` or with `/abs`, it only resolves hostnames (such as `www.example.com`) to IP addresses (such as `198.51.100.200`). Also, you can only try to ping either hostname or IP address (without `http://` and `/abs`).

Comment: thanks for clarification. I'll work other way.